# Host WCF service in WAS

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, was

I need some help with hosting a WCF service in WAS.
I hosted the service ok in IIS and accessed over basicHttp and wsHttp binding.
But it seems I miss something when trying to host it in WAS and access over tcp/ip.

I need to configure it for access over tcp on port 10000.

I enabled WCF activation for Non-HTTP in Windows Features

The service is published under default web site, application mywcfapp

I created a BAT file to enable net.tcp binding on port 10000 on default web site and mywcfapp as below:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set site "Default Web Site" -+bindings.[protocol='net.tcp',bindingInformation='10000:*']
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set app "Default Web Site/mywcfapp" /enabledProtocols:http,net.tcp
```

The web.config is

```
<services>
  <service name="MyWcfService">
    <clear />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"
      listenUriMode="Explicit" />

    <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:10000/mywcfapp/mywcfapp.svc"
      binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="PortSharingBinding" contract="MyApp.IService" />
    <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:10000/mywcfapp/mywcfapp.svc"
      binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="PortSharingBinding" contract="MyApp.IService" />

  </service>
</services>

<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="PortSharingBinding" portSharingEnabled="true">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

However, it seems I cannot access the service.

When I try to access the service with WcfTestClient with the uri

```
net.tcp://localhost:10000/mywcfapp/mywcfapp.svc/mex
```

I get the following error

```
<Fault xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<Code>
    <Value>Sender</Value>
    <Subcode><Value xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">a:DestinationUnreachable</Value>
    </Subcode>
</Code>
<Reason><Text xml:lang="ro-RO">
    The message with To 'net.tcp://localhost:10000/mywcfapp/mywcfapp.svc/mex' 
    cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch 
    at the EndpointDispatcher.  
    Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree.
</Text></Reason>
</Fault>
```

If I try to connect with url (w/o specifying port)

```
net.tcp://localhost/OneTest.Service/OneTest.Service.svc/mex
```

I get the error (kept only significant part)

```
Could not connect to net.tcp://localhost/mywcfapp/mywcfapp.svc/mex. 
The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:02.0041146. 
TCP error code 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:808.     
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:808
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help:

Go to IIS Manager.
Right click on the app.
Choose Manage Applications -> Advanced settings
Under Behavior, there is a field for Enabled Protocols.

Make sure it has `net.tcp`

If it just has `http`, change it to

```
http,net.tcp
```

Comment: Thanks, I checked and that was already enabled (I guess I enabled it when I run the BAT). However, I suspect the issue is somewhere with the port. strange is, if I include port (10000) in URI in WCF test client, the error is AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. If I don't include port in URI, it seems client is trying to connect to server on port 808, but why?

Comment: Make sure there is no space between http and net.tcp, just the comma.